# SQL UPDATE code not changing database data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to update my database through forms.

Part of the code is working because it retrieves data from the table and displays it in the form but the sql update code is not changing values at the backend.

Snippet of code is shown below, any help at all will be appreciated:

```
<html>
<head>
    <body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if(!$con){
die("Cannot Connect to database:" . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("intranet",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM progress_sheet";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE progress_sheet SET jobdescription='$_POST[jobdescription]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);    
};
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Job Description</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=save.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=jobdescription value=" . $record['jobdescription'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['hidden'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>  
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

*

Comment: try to see of there is an error also check the post data mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con)  or die(mysql_error())

Comment: Please pay attention, this could put you in a big trouble due to sql injection ...

Comment: Please check if isset the POST-Request you use for the update before you try to update with non set Params

Comment: What also worth mentioning that mysql_* functions are deprecated to mysqli_*

Comment: @Sedz after adding or die it returns "Query was empty"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code more than one errors are found,

1 Missing single quotes and double quotes.

2 The form is posted to another file `save.php` (quotes is also missing)

```
<html>
<head>
    <body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if(!$con){
die("Cannot Connect to database:" . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("intranet",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM progress_sheet";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$jobdescription = $_POST['jobdescription'];  // See here
$id = $_POST['hidden'];                      // See here
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE progress_sheet SET jobdescription='$jobdescription' WHERE id='$id'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);    
};
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Job Description</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";  // See Here. The form is posted to another page
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=jobdescription value=" . $record['jobdescription'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>  
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basic example with simple checks to prevent sql injections. Note that mysql functions are deprecated. You can use mysqli functions.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>

    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
        if(!$con){
            die("Cannot Connect to database:" . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("intranet",$con);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM progress_sheet";
        $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
        if(isset($_POST['update'])){

            //do basic checks to prevent sql injections
             $jobdescription = isset($_POST['jobdescription']) ? trim($_POST['jobdescription'] : '');
             $hidden = isset($_POST['hidden']) ? trim($_POST['hidden'] : '');

            $jobdescription = mysql_real_escape_string($jobdescription);
             $hidden = mysql_real_escape_string($hidden);



            if(empty($jobdescription) || empty($hidden)){

                //handle errors here
                //exit;
                //or do error logging $errors[] = "Your error message"
                //or redirect with header(...);
            }

            $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE progress_sheet SET jobdescription='$jobdescription' WHERE id='$hidden'";
            mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
        };
        echo "<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <th>Job Description</th>
        </tr>";
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
            echo "<form action=save.php method=post>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=jobdescription value=" . $record['jobdescription'] . " </td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['id'] . " </td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>  
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

At the top of your .php files you should enable error reporting, which will help you with debugging:

```
<?php
// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report runtime errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$UpdateQuery = 'UPDATE progress_sheet SET jobdescription="'.mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['jobdescription']) ? $_POST['jobdescription'] : '').'" WHERE id='.(isset($_POST['hidden']) ? $_POST['hidden']*1 : 0);
```

And stop using `mysql_*` functions and move to `mysqli_*` functions as the ones you are using are deprecated.

Comment: You have missing quotes around $_POST[jobdescription]

Comment: Yes, didnt thought there werent there, edited them in and added simple checing of existance of the variables.